# How to attach ConsumerRebalanceListener to ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, reactive

For non-reactive consumer, we can use consumer.subscribe to attach a listener:

```java
      KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
      consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("example-topic-2020-6-24"),
              new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                      System.out.printf("onPartitionsRevoked - consumerName: %s, partitions: %s%n", name,
                              formatPartitions(partitions));
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                      System.out.printf("onPartitionsAssigned - consumerName: %s, partitions: %s%n", name,
                              formatPartitions(partitions));
                  }
              });
```

How do we do it for ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly; instead you register listeners with the `ReceiveOptions`...

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/1c677186782be613385278fa500316e4bbb8dfaf/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/ReceiverOptions.java#L94-L114